# regex string substitution upper and lower case

Tags: php, regex, string, match, uppercase

Given the following simple function (for a PHP page) I am trying to match all the occurences of the word `$marker` in a long text string. I need to highlight its occurences.
The function works, but it presents two problems:

1) it fails to match uppercase occurences of `$marker`

2) it also matches partial occurences: if $marker is "*art*", the function as it is also matches "*artistic*" and "*cart*".

How can I correct these two inconveniences?

```
function highlightWords($string, $marker){
$string = str_replace($marker, "<span class='highlight success'>".$marker."</span>", $string);
return $string;
}
```

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but can't you just combine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/check-if-string-contains-specific-words and http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve the two problems you can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) with a regular expression. Just add the [`i` flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for case-insensitive search and add [`\b` word boundaries](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) around your search term, so it can't be part of another word, e.g.

```
function highlightWords($string, $marker){
    $string = preg_replace("/(\b" . preg_quote($marker, "/") . "\b)/i", "<span class='highlight success'>$1</span>", $string);
    return $string;
}
```

Comment: This solution matches both upper- and lower-case occurences, but it seems to return only lower case strings, transforming the original upper case.

Comment: @Alex Yes, I forgot to change that. I changed out the variable in the replace argument with `$1` which is the first capturing group, here: `(\b" . preg_quote($marker, "/") . "\b)`. So try it again and it should be as you wanted it.

Comment: Great.It does work! I didn't know about the use of groups (`$1`).